# How do I implement ViewModel inside a Fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin

I tried to implement ViewModel inside Fragment like this:

```
class myFragment: Fragment() {


    private val viewModelProvider by lazy { ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()) }
    private val myViewModel by lazy {
        viewModelProvider.get(
            ViewModel::class.java
        )
    }
    ....
    }
```

The error is:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.net2software.mobile.mpos_cirebon.debug, PID: 15298
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.mypackagename.viewmodel.viewmodelClass
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Fragment Extension

```
def fragment_version = "1.4.0"
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:$fragment_version"
```

Fragment View Model

```kotlin
private val viewModel by viewModels<ViewModel>()
```

Activity Shared ViewModel between fragments

```kotlin
private val activityViewModel by activityViewModels<ViewModel>()
```

Comment: I got an error, it said: 

The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
Dependency: androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.4.0.
AAR metadata file: C:\Users\lenovo.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\642b3a1daa9bf0ed0ed57b9f44a43ba8\jetified-fragment-ktx-1.4.0\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

Comment: change your `compileSdkVersion` to 31 or use a lower version for example `1.3.0`

Comment: alright, it can build

but I got confused... u said: 
Fragment View Model

private val viewModel by viewModels<ViewModel>( ),

how to implement this into my code...,

private val viewModelProvider by lazy { ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()) }
    private val myViewModel by lazy {
        viewModelProvider.get(

            ViewModel::class.java <- this is my viewmodel
        )
    }

and is it possible to implement viewmodel in fragment alone(without requireactivity) ?

Comment: Now you don't need to use  viewModelProvider to create view model just write `private val viewModel by viewModels<ViewModel>()` and inside viewModels<?> this is your view model class

Comment: thank you... it works... but got different error, it said: no injector found,

is there any supported injector for the lib you've mentioned ? I use dagger com.google.dagger:dagger:2.37

anyway, I'll upvote your answer for now

Comment: I Think your main problem is that you didn't create factory for your viewmodel, if you use Hilt you don't need it and just add @AndroidViewModel but with dagger you need to create factory and use `viewmodel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(ViewModel::class.java)`

Comment: yes... you're right, I just solved it, thank you... I will check your answer